# Standardize all numerical predictors in a regression formula

Tags: r, regression

How do you standardize only the numerical predictors in a linear model?

I know that I can simply scale the original numerical data. However, I want to write a function that takes an `lm` object as an argument and returns the standardized beta coefficients for the numerical predictors only.

Here is an example:

```
data(iris)
mod1 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data = iris)
summary(mod1)
mod1.b <- update(mod1, scale(.) ~ scale(.))
summary(mod1.b)
```

This works without problems. But when I include a factor, it gives an error message.

```
mod2 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Species, data = iris)
summary(mod2)
mod2.b <- update(mod2, scale(.) ~ scale(.)) #Gives an error
```

So, how can I scale only the numerical predictors in the second example?

Comment: Hi @johannes this question seems to be just about how to do something in R, so it is a better fit on StackOverflow.

Comment: @PeterFlom Seems like I missed the obvious - you are of course right. Could someone of the moderators move or close this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the design matrix of the lm object. For example, we could do the following:

```
design.matrix <- mod2$model

numeric.columns <- design.matrix[,unlist(lapply(design.matrix,is.numeric))]
scaled.numeric.columns <- scale(numeric.columns)
```

Now we replace the numeric columns in the data.frame with the scales ones:

```
design.matrix[,unlist(lapply(design.matrix,is.numeric))] <- scaled.numeric.columns
```

Finally, update the lm object:

```
mod2.b <- update(mod2, data = design.matrix)
```